# How to maintain background screen position while popup used?

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app.
I am using popup control in it. But when popup window come background page changes its position and it will go at bottom.
Problem: How to maintain background page at its original position when popup windows comes?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "background page changes its position and it will go at bottom"?

Comment: I am creating one page student ifo. and when I clicked on login then pop of login page come.(Login page popup is name of that page) When this popup comes student info page change its position and all text boxes buttons are going downwords

Comment: Can you put the screenshot into your question please?